# Error while installing CodeIgniter plugin in Netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

I have installed Netbeans 7.1.2 and I  need CodeIgniter framework on NetBeans. But while installing the plugin, following error message is displayed. How to fix it? I have already installed xampp on my windows also.
"some plugins require plugin PHP APIs to be installed
the plugin php apis is requested in implementation verssion 201203012225
the following plugin is affected
php CI framework"

Comment: What netbeans version did you install? The java version, the C++, the PHP or the all-inclusive? Looks like you're missing the php plugin, makes me think you got the "wrong" IDE

Comment: Please re-read my comment, I didn't ask for which version number, but which language your downloaded IDE is for

Comment: java version is already installed for my java projects, and i need codeigniter for php and i heard that netbeans ide can be used for codeigniter, so...

Comment: Yes, but if you go the the netbeans website, you'll see that Netbeans comes in various flavors; it can be a Java-only IDE (no PHP support), a C++ ide (no Java nor Php support), a PHP only ide (no Java and no c++) or a full-options (all languages supported). Which one of these do you have? Anyway, the php plugin can be installed separately. I'm just guessing, but your error is pretty straighforward

Comment: I uninstalled the previous one and installed netbeans ide 7.2.1(for php only), but i dont get codeigniter for 7.2.1 version, when i used http://kenai.com/downloads/nbphpci/Latest_NetBeans720/updates.xml this url(for netbeans 7.2.0), same error comes. what to do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20150/discussion-between-barcelona-tsandesh-and-damien-pirsy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to download using [this](http://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=windows&lang=en&option=php) link.It contains only PHP language

Comment: ok, i have downloaded netbeans 7.2.1 and installed it(from your link), but there is no codeigniter plugin for this version.. what to do? Update: My os is windows 07 64 bit

Comment: There no need to use any plugin for codeigniter. It work without plugin.
You can create new project of codeigniter without any plugin.
This is my personal experience.I am using the same